# Android application stops receiving c2dm messages after a while

Tags: android, android-c2dm

we've been trying to develop an android application which uses the c2dm service of Google.
When we start the application after clearing all data, the application receives the c2dm messages just fine, but after some time (maybe 2 minutes) the messages refuse to arrive.

We also checked the code we received after pushing the c2dm messages from the server, and the code was successful (code number 200 without error).

After searching relevant posts on Stack Overflow, we came across this post:
[Why do Android C2DM push messages not always arrive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243244/why-do-android-c2dm-push-messages-not-always-arrive)
but we verified that we don't register to the c2dm service each time the application starts.

What seems to be the problem in our case?

We use android 2.2 API 8 version .

Thanks in advance,
Mark.

Answer (score 2):

You should always have in mind that Google's C2DM allows a certain limit of messages/day. I'm thinking that sending a large number of messages in 2-3 minutes (a client-chat, or something like that) could be the source of your problem.

And also, have in mind that there is no guarantee whatsoever that messages will arrive. Per Google's C2DM Introduction: *C2DM makes no guarantees about delivery or the order of messages.* But you probably already know this.

I am thinking that if your 2-3 minute average is a rule, then probably the limitation of the messages could be the cause. Try sending fewer messages and see if the interval doesn't get larger.

Answer (score 0):

"maybe 2 minutes" - you should confirm that first of all. You must clarify:

- Is this issue related to this one device?
- Does it happen consistently? If not, what triggers it?
- Has it happened once, or does it happen every time?

Do bear in mind that C2DM messages are not guaranteed. Some will not arrive.

Also be aware that sometimes Android devices "fall off" c2dm and don't receive messages for a period of time. You will see similar effects on some networks (e.g. in my experience some C2DM messages are not delivered over wifi networks, so try 3G too).

Comment: Hello Ollie.
We have ran this application on many devices and emultors.
This problem happens every time, but it starts on random times, meaning sometimes it starts after minute and a half, and sometimes later.
However,it seems that this problem starts significantly earlier on real devices rather then on emulators.
Regarding the "some will not arrive" - it's not that some messages are received and some don't. Until a certain point in time **all** the messages arrive but from it **not one message** will arrive.

Comment: Are you sure they're not arriving, or just being delayed? Some C2DM messages arrive very fast, others take a while. In my experience at least.

Comment: Maybe we haven't waited enough time to make sure that the messages arrive. Thanks for your help anyway.